# Why is this simple libpqxx code leaking memory?

Tags: c++, postgresql, memory-leaks, libpqxx

Recently I wrote an application that accesses a Postgres DB via libpqxx, and it leaks memory badly.  Even this simple test program, which is based on the example at http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/4.0/html/Reference/a00001.html leaks like no tomorrow.

(Edit: I added calls to commit() and clear() in response to suggestions.  Same leakiness.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        pqxx::connection c("user=postgres");

        int i = 0;          
        while(true)
        {
            pqxx::work w(c);
            pqxx::result r = w.exec("SELECT 1");
            w.commit();

            i++;
            if ( i % 1000 == 0 )
                printf( "Cycle %d\n", i );

            r.clear();
        } //while
    } //try
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } //catch
} //main
```

After about 75,000 cycles of the loop, top shows 206Mb of virtual memory usage, and it keeps climbing.  I ran a similar test program with 5000 cycles through valgrind and got this:

```
==1647== 13,732,155 (219,868 direct, 13,512,287 indirect) bytes in 4,997 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 12 of 12
==1647==    at 0x40060D5: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:214)
==1647==    by 0x404C0A9: pqxx::result::result(pg_result*, int, std::string const&, int) (in /usr/lib/libpqxx-4.0.so)
==1647==    by 0x40309EF: pqxx::connection_base::make_result(pg_result*, std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libpqxx-4.0.so)
==1647==    by 0x4036D65: ??? (in /usr/lib/libpqxx-4.0.so)
==1647==    by 0x405EFD6: pqxx::transaction_base::DirectExec(char const*, int) (in /usr/lib/libpqxx-4.0.so)
==1647==    by 0x40416EA: pqxx::dbtransaction::do_exec(char const*) (in /usr/lib/libpqxx-4.0.so)
==1647==    by 0x40618FA: pqxx::transaction_base::exec(std::string const&, std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libpqxx-4.0.so)
==1647==    by 0x80498F8: main (dbtest.cpp:21)
```

Any idea what's going on?  It's very difficult to accept that a widely used library like libpqxx would have such a severe bug, so what might I be doing wrong here?

Configuration details:

- OS: Linux 2.6.18-238.el5
- gcc version 4.4.0
- libpqxx 4.0
- postgres 9.2

(**Final edit: I found it easier to replace libpqxx with libpq than to keep investigating this memory leak.**)

Comment: The examples show a w.commit() is needed after the exec() call. Can you add that and try your test again ?

Comment: @VaibhavDesai Yeah, I tried that but the leak remained.  Thanks

Comment: Which version do you use (libpqxx, PostgreSql, gcc, ...)? Could you add the `Makefile` please. I could not reproduce your problem using the Debian packages (its 2.6.9, stone age, "old, but stable").

Comment: @Beryllium Thanks, I just added some configuration details to the question.  It's being built via scons, not make, and the sconscript isn't very illuminating.

Answer (score 3):

I could not reproduce your problem.

Neither with libpqxx-2.6.9 nor with libpqxx-4.0.1 (at this time the current stable version).

- Debian Linux 2.6.32
- gcc version 4.4.5
- libpq5 8.4.17
- libpqxx 4.0.1
- libstdc++ 6.4.4
- postgres 8.4

Memory usage is constant.

> $ valgrind --tool=memcheck run.sh
>   [...]
>   Cycle 35000
>   Cycle 36000
>   ^C==18420==
>   ==18420== HEAP SUMMARY:
>   ==18420==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==18420==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
>   ==18420==
>   ==18420== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible

I would check, if you have a problem with different installations of the libraries you are using. For example, do you link against libpqxx-4.0, but later on, when you run the program, you are using a different version.

> $ ldd client
>   linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7776000)
>   libpqxx-4.0.so => not found
>   libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb7669000)
>   libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb764a000)
>   libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7503000)
>   libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb74ea000)
>   libm.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb74c4000)
>   /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7777000)

As I have downloaded and installed libpqxx-4.0.1 manually, I have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` explicitly, since I have not installed it below `/usr/local/`. If different versions are installed in `/usr/local`, you should cleanup there before.

In your case (using `ldd`) libpqxx should point to the version you have compiled and installed. Make sure that there is only one libpqxx installed on your system.

I used this `Makefile`

> CPPFLAGS += -I/home/dev/data/src/cpp/libpqxx-4.0.1/install/include
>   LDFLAGS += -L/home/dev/data/src/cpp/libpqxx-4.0.1/install/lib -lpqxx -lstdc++
>
> client: client.o

and libpqxx has been built with

> ./configure --prefix=/home/dev/data/src/cpp/libpqxx-4.0.1/install --enable-shared
>   make
>   make install

and I have run the program using

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/dev/data/src/cpp/libpqxx-4.0.1/install/lib client

Comment: Thanks, what you say makes sense.  The ldd output shows this:         libpqxx-4.0.so => /usr/lib/libpqxx-4.0.so (0x00852000)
libpq.so.5 => /usr/pgsql-9.2/lib/libpq.so.5 (0x00a24000)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that pqxx::result is leaking memory. Try adding:

```
r.clear();
```

It will at least reduce the leaking.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        pqxx::connection c("user=postgres");

        int i = 0;  

        while(true)
        {
            pqxx::work w(c);
            pqxx::result r = w.exec("SELECT 1");

            i++;
            if ( i % 1000 == 0 )
                printf( "Cycle %d\n", i );

            r.clear();
        } //while
    } //try
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } //catch
} //main
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that earlier and it didn't stop the leaking.  I updated the code in my question though.

Comment: It's very likely to be a bug then. I can't see anything you're doing wrong.

Comment: I changed my code to use libpq instead of libpqxx, and the leak is gone.  So, you might be right.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare pqxx::result r whitout the while. And call it inside, as you are doing. Because for each cycle of the while, you are creating a pqxx::result object. In this way you will create just one object to all the loop, to charge and clear in each cycle:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        pqxx::connection c("user=postgres");

        int i = 0;          
        pqxx::result r;
        while(true)
        {
            pqxx::work w(c);
            r = w.exec("SELECT 1");
            w.commit();

            i++;
            if ( i % 1000 == 0 )
                printf( "Cycle %d\n", i );

            r.clear();
        } //while
    } //try
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } //catch
} //main
```

Or even better, create a method to call in each cycle of the while, so, when each call of the method finish, tne temporary object will gone.

```
main()
{
    ...
    while()
    {
        ...
        method_to_call_pqxx();
    }
}
```